How to draw a rectangle at (x,y) in a PyQt GraphicsView?
I'm learning Python and Qt, and as an exercise I designed a simple window in QT Designer with a QGraphicsView which would represent a stack data structure. It should hold the items on the stack as a rectangle with a label representing the item, but my problem is that I can't position the rectangle at(x,y). Google and the documentation didn't help.
Maybe it's a simple oversight or it's just me being dumb.
This code draws a rectangle in the center of the QGraphicsView, and it should(if I understand correctly)place a 10x10 rectangle at 10,10:
class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Stack.ui', self) 
        
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
    
        self.scene.addRect(QRectF(10,10,10,10))
        
app=QApplication([])

window=Ui()
window.show()
app.exec()

Stack.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
 <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
   <x>0</x>
   <y>0</y>
   <width>800</width>
   <height>600</height>
  </rect>
 </property>
 <property name="windowTitle">
  <string>MainWindow</string>
 </property>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="1">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="0" rowspan="3">
    <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="3">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Push</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="3">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Pop</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>24</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
</widget>
<resources/>
<connections/>
</ui>


Your rectangle is positioned correctly.  The problem you're seeing is due to the fact that the top-left corner of the scene is not anchored to the top-left corner of the view.  Try setting the scene rect explicitly using QGraphicsView::setSceneRect.

You are right, that improved it, although the y coordinate is still messed up when I set the scene rect. How can I do it in the designer, to keep the code as clean as possible?

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Stack.ui', self)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.graphicsView.setSceneRect(0, 0, 250, 250)  # adjust as needed
        self.graphicsView.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.scene.addRect(QRectF(10, 10, 10, 10))


app = QApplication([])

window = Ui()
window.show()
app.exec()


This solved my problem,although it's possible to set these properties in the designer, which I prefer.Anyway, thank you very much!

Doing this in the Qt Designer, I think that you want to use alignment and sceneRect. This will make the alignment right and also the x and y offsets right.

Problem solved,thank you again! I just had to change the alignment property.

Create a QGraphicsScene: This is where your graphical items (like the rectangle) will be added.
Add a rectangle item to the scene: You can use the QGraphicsRectItem for this.
Set the scene to the QGraphicsView: The view is responsible for displaying the scene and its items.
Here's an example of how to draw a rectangle at (x, y):
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
def init(self):
super().init()
    # Create a QGraphicsScene
    self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
    self.setScene(self.scene)

    # Define the x, y position and the width, height of the rectangle
    x, y = 50, 50
    width, height = 100, 100

    # Create a QGraphicsRectItem (rectangle) and set its position and size
    rect_item = QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF(x, y, width, height))

    # Add the rectangle item to the scene
    self.scene.addItem(rect_item)

if name == 'main':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a window with the custom QGraphicsView
view = MyGraphicsView()
view.setWindowTitle("PyQt GraphicsView Rectangle Example")
view.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())


This does not answer the question. The OP already knows how to create a rect at given coordinates, the problem is that it's not shown where they expect. Note that your question seem to be created with a generative AI, and such contents is banned on SO. Maybe it's not your case, but if you did use an AI for this answer, I suggest you to remove the post, as violating that rule can result in account suspension. Also, always check the post preview before submitting, and ensure that you properly format code.
